# Bowyer-Watson Delaunay Triangulation neighbour walk in $O(n^{1/d})$

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, computational-geometry, nearest-neighbour

The Bowyer-Watson Algorithm for creating Delaunay Triangulations works iteratively. Let's say that we have a Delaunay triangulation of $n-1$ points. Now we add the $n$-th point. In order to update the edges, we first need to find the nearest neighbour to that new point.

They propose to start at the vertex nearest to the center and then walking along it's neighbours in the direction of the point (remember, we have an euclidian metric). Finding all direct neighbours of a vertex is possible in $\mathcal{O}(1)$ since the number of neighbours is limited implicitly by the optimal equilaterality of an Delaunay triangulation.

Both [Green and Sibson's 2D Algorithm](https://doi.org/10.1093/comjnl/21.2.168) and [Bowyer's nD Generalization](https://doi.org/10.1093/comjnl/24.2.162) claim that this walk takes $\mathcal{O}(n^{1/d})$ where $d$ is the dimension.

Why is that I don't even have an intuition for $d=2$, although I have a feeling that it somehow relates to reducing the problem into 4 quadrants by splitting it in the middle, i.e.

```
-----------
|    |    |
|    |    |
|---------|
|    |    |
|    |    |
-----------
```

I haven't found anything in the internet and [Fortune 1995](https://doi.org/10.1142/9789812831699_0007) concluded that

> Bowyer suggests that a walk starting from a site near the centroid of the Delaunay triangulation should visit about $\mathcal{O}(n^{1/d})$ cells, **although no rigorous analysis is known**.

EDIT: It can't be that hard, but I really don't have a clue at all. [Aurenhammer 1991](https://doi.org/10.1145/116873.116880) p. 361 even mentions that

> [...] but a *simple* heuristic will archive $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{i})$ expected time.